# Crear prueba JMeter para comprobar conexiones

Tags: websocket, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

Tengo una aplicación que cuenta con un backend de administración y un frontend donde se muestran los datos. Cuando modifico alguna cosa tengo un gestor de notificaciones.

Para acceder al backend o frontend mediante pruebas de JMeter puedo hacer peticiones del estilo "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/backend". Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer alguna prueba en JMeter (con webdriver si es necesario) para comprobar todas la notificaciones cuando se modifica algo, y saber cual es el límite total de notificaciones.

Acepto cualquier sugerencia. Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: ¿En qué tecnología está implementado un gestor de notificaciones?

Comment: En Django-python